# Python: Change tuple in a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I am trying to replace a value in a tuple in a list of tuples.

```
recordlist = [(sku,item,bro),(sku1,item1,bro1),...]

for item in recordlist:
    itemlist = list(item)
    if itemlist[0] == 'sku':
        itemlist[1] = itemlist[1]+',item'
        item = tuple(itemlist)

        print(item)
```

This code currently is not working. Can someone help?
the current output shows

```
('sku','item','bro')
```

Expected output is:

```
('sku','item,item','bro')
```

Comment: Please explain what not working means. What is your expectation of what should be happening, what is currently happening?

Comment: ok. let me edit

Comment: Please check now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think assigning the updated `tuple` to the corresponding index in the `list` will solve the issue since `tuples` are immutable. To keep the corresponding index `enumerate` can be used while iterating through the list. You can try following:

```
recordlist = [('sku1','item1','bro1'),('sku2','item2','bro2')]

for index, item in enumerate(recordlist):
    itemlist = list(item)
    if itemlist[0] == 'sku1':
        itemlist[1] = itemlist[1]+','+'item'
    item = tuple(itemlist)

    recordlist[index] = item

print(recordlist)
```

Output:

```
[('sku1', 'item1,item', 'bro1'), ('sku2', 'item2', 'bro2')]
```

Comment: This one shows the following error message:                                
    ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: My list contains 5449 items

Comment: @Santosh what is the error message? Can you please give more details on which line and what the message is?

Comment: 77                     else:
`---> 78                         for index, item in recordlist:`
     `79                             itemlist = list(item)`
  `80                             if itemlist[0] == sku:`

`ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

Comment: @Santosh in line 78 or 77 wherever it is, It has to be `index, item in enumerate(recordlist)`

Comment: Thanks bro. I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

Lists are useful data structures when you want to work with modifiable elements. Tuples are immutable. Current code might be inefficient for large amounts of data as you constantly convert a tuple into a list, modify an element and back into tuples. The following code does the same but works with lists.

```
recordlist = [['sku','item','bro'],['sku1','item1','bro1']]

for itemlist in recordlist:
    if itemlist[0] == 'sku':
        itemlist[1] = itemlist[1]+',item'
        print(tuple(itemlist))
```