# Replace elements of tuples from list of tuples - Python

Tags: python, list, tuples

I want to write a python program to replace last value of tuples in a list with a certain number (lets say 100).

my list: `[(10,20,30),(40,50,60),(70,80,90)]`

expected output: `[(10,20,100),(40,50,100),(70,80,100)]`

Comment: You can't change a tuple. You could make a new one though

Answer (score 5):

Since tuples are immutable, you will have to reassemble new ones:

```
lst = [(10,20,30),(40,50,60),(70,80,90)]

new_lst = [tpl[:-1] + (100,) for tpl in lst]
# [(10, 20, 100), (40, 50, 100), (70, 80, 100)]
```

This uses a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) over the new tuples, which are concatenations of the appropriate [slices](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/brackets/slicing.html) with a singleton tuple (`(100,)`). Note that the comma is important.

Comment: Thanks, this works but can you explain the second line in short

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> lst = [(10,20,30), (40,50,60), (70,80,90)]
>>> [(*t[:-1], 100) for t in lst]
[(10, 20, 100), (40, 50, 100), (70, 80, 100)]
```

similar to schwobaseggl's answer, but rather than appending to a tuple with `+` operator, I prefer to unpack the elements desired. The benefit of doing so is readability.

## explanation

for every tuple `t` in the list `lst`, we apply `(*t[:-1], 100)`.

In python, negative indices gets you the element in a list/tuple counting backwards, so `[-1]` gets you the last item. `[a:b]` gets you the ath item to the b-1th item. So `t[:-1]` gets you items in `t` upto the one before the last one.

`*` operator unpacks the slice. and puts them in the new tuple alongside with `100`. So it is equivalent to `(.., .., .., .., 100)` and the ".." represents all the items unpacked, which in this case is the items in tuple `t` excluding the last item.

Hope you found this helpful and maybe earned something :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use list comprehension in this case.

But one problem you can come across when trying this is modifying the tuple. So a workaround would be to use `list()` in order to convert the tuple to a list to make it mutable.

Then we need to take all the elements before the last and concatenate that with `100`.

Note that `list(tup)+100` won't work because the list can only concrete with another list.

```
org = [(10,20,30),(40,50,60),(70,80,90)]
new = [tuple(list(tup[:-1])+[100]) for tup in org]
print(new)
```

output

```
[(10, 20, 100), (40, 50, 100), (70, 80, 100)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this case earlier :
[Python: Change tuple in a list of tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44751916/python-change-tuple-in-a-list-of-tuples)

OR You can go through this link for better understanding:

[Replace tuple according to Nth tuple element](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-replace-tuple-according-to-nth-tuple-element/)